# How to Search and output from Meteor Collection

Tags: meteor

**The JS**

```
Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors");

Template.col_list.cols = function () {
  return Colors.find();
};
```

So this code will output everything from Col.find into the handlebar cols in the html

**The HTML**

```
{{#each cols}}
{{name}}, {{RGB}}, {{HEX}}
{{/each}}
```

But say I want to have a input box so I can search for a name of the color, so it only shows the information for that color or any color that starts with whatever I type into the input box.

example:
Input = "bl"
output should be black, blue or whatever else that starts with bl.

I've been looking everywhere for any example of this in practice yet I haven't found any.

Far as I have gotten so far is something to this effect yet it yields no luck.

```
Template.col_list.events({
  'click .search': function() {
    Colors.find(name: $('col_name').val());
  }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make the content of the template depend on the input field in a way that preserves the reactivity of Meteor. Session variables are great for that.

This should work:

```
Colors = new Meteor.Collection("colors");

Template.col_list.cols = function () {
  return Colors.find({name: { $regex: Session.get('prefix')+".*", $options: 'i' }});
};

Template.col_list.events({
  'click .search': function() {
    Session.set('prefix', $('.col_name').val());
  }
});
```

Comment: tried it, nothing happened, tried adding alert('Searching for ' + $('col_name').val()); It says that im searching for undefined :/

Comment: tried adding undefined to the database and it finds undefined :P so we know it should work but why is it undefined?

Comment: We will need to see your input HTML for that, i.e., where us col_name defined? BTW, you probably mean "#col_name", no?

Comment: <input type="text" class="col_name">

Comment: OK, then your jquery selector was off. I've updated my answer. You need to use ".col_name" to find that element. Does this fix the "undefined" issue?

Comment: indeed it does :D silly me I knew that it needed to be .classname yet somehow when I retyped the javascript I didnt put a . there :S Thanks so much for the help

Comment: final short question: do you know how I can make it so it doesnt care if the name is capitalized or not.

Comment: Yes. I've updated the answer once more (you need to add the 'i' option to the regex).