# Search a collection in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create a small-scale meteor app to search a mongodb collection for any data that I've already added to it.

I have it currently displaying the entire collection, but if I enter a search string into a form, I would like it to only display the mongodb entries that contain that same search string. Here's what I've got on it so far.

app.js:

```
Persons = new Mongo.Collection("persons");

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.body.helpers({
  persons: function() {
    return Persons.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}});
  }
});

Template.person.persons({
  "submit .person-search": function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var input = event.target.text.value;

    return Persons.find({
      text: input
    });
  }
});
```

The search form in app.html

```
<form class = "person-search">
  <input type = "text" name = "text" placeholder = "Type to search for people" />
</form>
```

The collection display in app.html

```
<ul>
  {{#each persons}}
    {{> person}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Whenever I enter a search string, the collection will refresh, but will continue to show all the data in the collection. I've tried using using sessions, like this, which I got from here: [How to Search and output from Meteor Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20664758/how-to-search-and-output-from-meteor-collection)

```
Template.person.persons = function() {
  return Persons.find({
  person: { $regex: Session.get('prefix') + ".*", $options: 'i'}});
};

Template.person.events({
  "submit .person-search": function() {
  Session.set('prefix', $('.person-search').val());
  }
});
```

However this didn't seem to work out for me. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you all for your time.